# A pseudo-random number generator based on 2 inputs

Tags: c, algorithm, random

I need to generate a pseudo-random number based on 2 input values X and Y. Given the same X and Y values I need to get the same result. The result should be between 0 and 1 inclusive.

So far I have this:

```
const int a = 0x7fffffff / 48271;
const int b = 0x7fffffff % 48397;

float rand(int x, int y) {
    float seed, result;

    seed = x ^ ((y << 1) & 0x2AAAAAAA) ^ ((y >> 1) & 0x33333333);
    result = 48353 * (seed % a) - b * (seed / a);

    return (result);
}
```

It's giving me a result but not what I'm looking for. I've cobbled it together from random things I've seen on the net, so no idea if it's really any good.

Comment: what is your question? It is hard to guess what do you mean "not what I'm looking for". Also good random numbers generator can not be constructed by just randomly looking something on the net.

Comment: Using unsigned math is a good step 1.

Comment: I think you want would be nearer a [tag:hash] than an RNG.

Comment: Are the 2 input types `int` (maybe 32, 64, 16 bit) or `signed 32-bit`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Borrowing from [xxHash](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash/blob/master/xxhash.c):

```
float rand(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
  /* mix around the bits in x: */
  x = x * 3266489917 + 374761393;
  x = (x << 17) | (x >> 15);

  /* mix around the bits in y and mix those into x: */
  x += y * 3266489917;

  /* Give x a good stir: */
  x *= 668265263;
  x ^= x >> 15;
  x *= 2246822519;
  x ^= x >> 13;
  x *= 3266489917;
  x ^= x >> 16;

  /* trim the result and scale it to a float in [0,1): */
  return (x & 0x00ffffff) * (1.0f / 0x1000000);
}
```

The general idea is to subject `x` and `y` to a variety of 1:1 transforms and to mix those together to distribute all of the input bits evenly(ish) throughout the result.  Then the result in floating-point to [0,1).  I've excluded 1.0 from the possible outputs because including it turns out to be kind of fiddly.

Multiplication by any odd number, with unsigned overflow, is a 1:1 transform because odd numbers are all co-prime with powers of two (the range limit of a `uint32_t`).  Unfortunately multiplication only allows low order bits to affect high order bits; it doesn't allow high bits to affect low.  To make up for that, we have a few `x ^= x >> k` terms, to mix high bits into low positions.

Answer (score 0):

To "get the same result" the PRNG state needs to be at least as many bits as the sum of `x,y` bit-width.  `float` is not wide enough.

By "same result", I assume that means the same sequence of numbers generated.

`long double` *might* work for you, but it appears you need a new PRNG algorithm with a much wider state.